# Windows npm vue errors during install and run dev

Tags: node.js, windows, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I am trying to make development environment working, but since 2 days unsuccessful.
As far as I can see, on Ubuntu all works with following stuff:

```
Python 2.7.18
Node 16.18.0
npm 8.19.2
gcc 9.4.0
```

It also worked with Node 14.17.5.

On Windows, I have:

```
Python 2.7.18
Node 14.17.5
npm 6.14.14
gcc command not found however I've installed windows build tools 1.4.2
```

scripts to run:

```
npm install
npm run dev - "dev": "HOST=0.0.0.0 NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 nuxt",
```

some dependencies:

```
"@nuxt/http": "^0.3.8",
"nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.2",
"@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
"@nuxtjs/recaptcha": "^1.0.4",
"nuxt": "^2.13.3",
"nuxt-i18n": "^6.14.2",
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"vuex": "^3.0.1"
```

dev dep.:

```
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
```

I've tried:
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@1.4.2
npm install -g node-gyp
npm config set python /d/Software/Python/Python27
npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
npm config set python python2.7

switching to newest npm and 16.9.0 (all with nvm).
Currently with 14.17.5, npm install goes ok with some unsupported npm version for some modules, but that is not a problem, node_modules and package-lock are created.
npm run dev gives me:

```
someProject@1.0.0 dev D:\Projects\someProject
HOST=0.0.0.0 NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 nuxt

'HOST' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

npm 16.19.0
npm install gives me:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     0 Warning(s)
npm ERR!     1 Error(s)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Time Elapsed 00:00:01.40
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Projects\someProject\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\Software\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Projects\\someProject\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\someProject\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.19.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-05T08_00_04_691Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried to do sudo apt install node-gyp but still this is the most recent error I am getting:

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```